# Excel function formula in single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can I enter a number from 1 to 20 in one cell and that same cell automatically multiply by $2.25 and give me the total

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with a formula to have the cell change itself like that.

You would need to use a Macro, or have the formula in a different cell.

IE in Cell A1 you enter 15
In Cell A2 you enter '=a1*2.25'

Cell A2 would show $33.75

If you want to use a macro, look at the Worksheet Change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    if Target.Address = "$A$1" then

         'code to perform something

    End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by John C, you cannot do this directly.

An alternative solution to what he posted would be to create a list with the total values of what you want, so the user can then click the cell, and select the correct value from the list.

To do this, Open the tab Data, and choose Data validation. Select Allow->List and fill in all the numbers separated by ; (so 2.25;4.50;6.75; etc) (you can also write these numbers down in your excelsheet, and click the little button at the end of the formula to select these cells.

Now, each time someone clicks that cell, a list will pop up and they can choose that number, rather than typing it in.